# require("jpgJs") returns an empty {} in my nodejs project

Tags: node.js, webpack, requirejs, jpeg

`require("jpgJs")` returns an empty `{}` in my nodejs project

I'm using [Utif](https://github.com/photopea/UTIF.js) in my react project and it has [jpgjs](https://github.com/notmasteryet/jpgjs) as a dependency.

Stepping through the code, `jpgjs` seems to not set it's `module.exports`.

On line 102 of `jpg.js`

```
if (typeof exports === "function") {
    module.exports = {
        JpegImage: JpegImage,
        JpegDecoder: JpegDecoder,
        JpxDecoder: JpxDecoder,
        Jbig2Decoder: Jbig2Decoder
    };
}
```

It is never going into the `if statement`. If I force it to go into that code, `JpegDecoder` (the piece `Utif` needs) is set to `undefined`.

If I move

```
module.exports = {
    JpegImage: JpegImage,
    JpegDecoder: JpegDecoder,
    JpxDecoder: JpxDecoder,
    Jbig2Decoder: Jbig2Decoder
};
```

to the very end of `jpg.js`, it sets `jpegDecoder` to the correct value and I can require it from my code but the require call in `Utif` does not work.

Has anybody used `jpgjs` in a node project and seen this issue?

Thanks

Comment: I have not used it, but that seems to be a major bug. I'd submit an issue on github about that because `exports` should never be a `function` in any environment. If an issue like that which prevents usage at all of the module exists, I'd be very skeptical as to the integrity of the rest of the code, and would consider choosing another dependency to use instead. **Edit** I see [you've already done that](https://github.com/notmasteryet/jpgjs/issues/43).

Comment: I believe this code is also forked from mozilla/pdfjs so this would be a bug in their system as well correct? Nevermind, I see that mozilla forked jpgjs and looks like they made some additional changes.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else needs the answer, I forked jpgjs to my github and put in the fix I need. I submitted a pull request to jpgjs but they are unresponsive.

https://github.com/makr28/jpgjs

The if statement should be checking if exports === "object" and it should be after the elements it is exporting are defined.